# Single-liner to write to file in Python

Tags: python

How do I perform the below write-to-file task in an easier or one-liner way?

```
>>> log="/tmp/test_write.log"
>>> file = open(log, "a")
>>> file.write("x" * 10)
>>> file.write("\n")
>>> file.close()
```

Is there some like this (bash/shell) in Python?

```bash
log="/tmp/test_write.log"
printf "`printf 'x%0.s' {1..10}`\n" >> $log
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need call `write` and `close`, the only (not completely insane) way to write just a single line is to separate the two commands by a `;`, which is horrible to read.

You can write a readable two-liner with the `with` statement:

```
with open("/tmp/test_write.log", "a") as log:
    log.write("x"*10 + '\n')
```

Files are context managers and using the `with` statement ensures that the file is closed once you exit the block.

Comment: Even though it is not pythonic way, you can have the `with` and `write` in one line.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('file', 'w') as pf:
    pf.write('contents\n')
```

If one line is important, it’s perfectly fine to use:

```
with open('file', 'w') as pf: pf.write('contents\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this by using `print`

Since file object normally contains `write()` method, all you need to do is to pass a file object into its argument.

Write/Append to a File like below:

```
with open("/tmp/test_write.log", 'a') as f:
    print("x"*10, file=f)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier (imo) way;

[from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text)

```
>>> p = Path('my_text_file')
>>> p.write_text('Text file contents')
18
>>> p.read_text()
'Text file contents'
```

So, in a one-liner you can write;

```
Path("path/to/my-file.txt").write_text("My Text to write.")
```